# Mi pagina carga lento al tomar datos de Steam

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo un problema con mi pagina y es que al activar para poder obtener las foto de steam de los jugadores mi pagina empieza a cargar lento al desactivar esta funcion la pagina vuelve a cargar rapido, realice una api para obtener dichas fotos el cual es

```html
<?php

global $key;
$key = '029014957D9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX59ECF5';

function getImagen($steamid)
{
    if (strpos($steamid, ":")) {
        return getSteamImg($steamid);
    }
    return 'images/default_avatar.jpg';
}

function getSteamImg($steamid64)
{
    global $key;

    $steamid64 = getSteam64($steamid64);
    
    $url = "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$key&steamids=$steamid64&format=json";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($response, false);
    
    if (isset($json->response->players[0]->avatarfull)) {
        $avatar = $json->response->players[0]->avatarfull;
        return $avatar;
    }
}

function getSteam64($steamid)
{
    if (strpos($steamid, ":")) {
        $split = explode(":", $steamid);
        $z = $split[2];
        $steamid64 = $z * 2 + 61197960265728;
        
        if ($split[1] == 1) {
            $steamid64 += 1;
        }
        
        $steamid64 = "765$steamid64";
        return $steamid64;
    }
}
?>
```

esto lo tengo guardado en un php y lo llamo de esta manera
**require_once("../../steam.php");**

y para usarlo lo hago de esta manera

```html
$avatar = getImagen($admins['steamid']);

if (!$avatar) {
    $avatar = "../../../img/default_avatar.jpg";
}

<img style="width: 20px;border-radius: 5px;" src="<?php echo $avatar ?>">
```

no se si es por la forma en la que obtengo la imagen que haga que cargue lento la pagina es la primera vez que realizo esta api y no se si este bien optimizada